# Athens during March - are attractions open?

Tags: europe, greece, athens

We will be travelling to Athens in March and I just wanted to check if the attractions will still be open as it will be the off season, and if so what days?

Comment: Which attractions in particular?

Comment: @Traveller It doesn't really matter: the significant attractions are open year-round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall (I lived in Athens about ten years ago), the museums, archaeological sites and so on are open all year round. Places will be closed at Christmas and for the Easter weekend but neither of those apply to your visit.